# How to mutate error response from Promise.allSettled?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, async-await, promise

I'm currently using Promise.allSettled and am mutating a successful response. However, I cannot figure out how to mutate the error response. It will always return an object for each promise of:

```
{ status: error, reason: reasonObject }
```

I would like to add two properties to the object so I can track the IDs and other meta data.

This is how I'm currently adding two keys to a successful response:

```
const results = await Promise.allSettled(
        batchedPayloads.map(async (payload, idx) => {
          return { accountId: payload && payload?.accountId, tag: payload?.tagId, result: await mutation(payload) };
        })
```

I would like to do the same to an error response, while still using async/await

Comment: What properties do you want to add to the error, and what do you mean, you want to keep using async/await? What needs to be async/await for the error?

Comment: I would like to add the same properties as the successful response to the error response object. `accountId` and `tag`. So the error object would be `{ status, reason, accountId, tag }` I meant that I'm using async/await within the `map` and would like to keep doing that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `.catch` onto the call of `mutation` so that if there's an error, it returns the desired object structure. Do this inside the `allSettled` loop. To be concise, define the object of properties to be added in advance.

```
const results = await Promise.allSettled(
    batchedPayloads.map(payload => {
        // properties to add
        const obj = { accountId: payload && payload?.accountId, tag: payload?.tagId };
        return mutation(payload)
            .then(result => ({ result, ...obj }))
            .catch((error) => {
                Object.assign(error, obj);
                // throw here so that allSettled shows this in the error section
                throw error;
            })
    })
);
```

Comment: I cannot chain `.then` after `mutation(payload)` for some reason. Nothing happens when I do this. `Cannot call 'mutation(...).then' because property 'then' is missing in  undefined `. I can only call `.then` after the `Promise.allSettled` invocation

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If `mutation(payload)` doesn't return a Promise, why are you `await`ing it in your original code?

Comment: I believe I used `await` in error. I just needed to use `async` without the `await` to make it return a promise.

Comment: Why use `Promise.allSettled` at all, then? If this code is entirely synchronous, using `Promise.allSettled` would seem to only add unnecessary confusion..?

Comment: Do you want to clarify?

Comment: Unsure when adding a .then() doesnt do anything because this performs a mutation and returns data.

Comment: You say that the `mutation` call doesn't return something with a `.then`, which means it doesn't return a Promise - and since it doesn't return a Promise, using either `await` or `Promise.allSettled` doesn't make any sense, since it's apparently synchronous, right? Do you just need a `try`/`catch`, or maybe not even that - just map to a new array while calling `mutation`?